# How to dectect modification on page? Which Listener in java?

Tags: java, aem

Is there any Listener in Java, which can detect, if the content of the page has been changed? "changed" means text in the page has been added/removed...

Process: Author modifys the page and activate it. In publish Instance it must be checked if the page content has been modified/changed

Comment: why would you want to check on the publish instance if the page has been modified?

Comment: This is specific to the function I will implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such listener. You're gonna have to reload/access the page or you can hook it up so when the author submits his changes you insert a value to the database that this specific page has been modified. After that you just read the data from the DB using a timer that triggers every now and then and if new line appears you do your action.

This is more of a design question and you should think about what project you're working on and what's the best approach to implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Apache sling can handle events. There is nice tutorial here http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/how-to-manage-events-in-sling.html .

Basically create a listener ad check if the event relates to a page node (or its subnode). Then apply whatever logic you want.

Be careful to check whether you are in an author or publish instance ( or turn off the service in author)